# Extract the breakpoints from cut

Tags: r

The documentation of the `cut` function gives "one way to extract the breakpoints"

```
aaa <- c(1,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5,6,7)
labs <- levels(cut(aaa, 3))
cbind(lower = as.numeric( sub("\\((.+),.*", "\\1", labs) ),
      upper = as.numeric( sub("[^,]*,([^]]*)\\]", "\\1", labs) ))

#      lower upper
# [1,] 0.994  3.00
# [2,] 3.000  5.00
# [3,] 5.000  7.01
```

Is there another - build-in - way to extract the breakpoints?

Comment: You can simplify the regex a bit: `as.numeric(sub('.(.+),.+', '\\1', labs));
as.numeric(sub('.+,(.+).', '\\1', labs))`

Answer (score 7):

**1) read.table** I don't think there is anything directly intended for this but this is shorter:

```
read.table(text = gsub("[^.0-9]", " ", labs), col.names = c("lower", "upper"))
```

giving this data.frame:

```
  lower upper
1 0.994  3.00
2 3.000  5.00
3 5.000  7.01
```

**2) gsubfn::strapply** and this is another possibility:

```
library(gsubfn)

strapply(labs, "[.0-9]+", as.numeric, simplify = rbind)
```

giving this matrix:

```
      [,1] [,2]
[1,] 0.994 3.00
[2,] 3.000 5.00
[3,] 5.000 7.01
```

**3) gsubfn::read.pattern** and another:

```
library(gsubfn)

read.pattern(text = labs, pattern = ".(.+),(.+).", col.names = c("lower", "upper"))
```

giving:

```
  lower upper
1 0.994  3.00
2 3.000  5.00
3 5.000  7.01
```

Comment: nice answer. In case someone has high numbers it'll use scientific notation, and the `e` will screw up the format... so use this regex instead: `gsub(pattern = "[\\]\\(),]",replacement = " ", x = labs,perl = TRUE)` for option 1 using `read.table`

Comment: One suggestion if you have negative numbers in your breakpoints: use `gsub("[^.0-9%-]", " ", labs)` instead of `gsub("[^.0-9]", " ", labs)` this way the negative sign will be retained. I realized the original code was turning negative breakpoints into positive breakpoints the hard way...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `strsplit()`:

```
sapply(strsplit(labs, "\\(|,|]"), function(x) as.numeric(x[-1]))
#       [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,] 0.994    3 5.00
# [2,] 3.000    5 7.01
```